# How to switch from using mysql.createConnection to mysql.createPool

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm fairly new to how database connections work using `nodejs`, and I'm having issues with database connections that aren't being closed properly.  I've asked a few questions on here before about it, and it seems like everyone is telling me to use `pool` instead of the way I have been doing it.  The only problem is that when I search online about using `pool` from `promise-mysql`, everyone seems to use a very simple and generic approach, but I'm using it within a complex application using `sockets`.  So I'm wondering how I can switch my old approach using `createConnection()` to using `pool` instead, in hopes of clearing up these connection issues.

Each time I call a socket it makes a connection to the database and then releases it after it is complete, or so it seems.  It sounds like this is not a very scalable approach, and that using `pool` will help run multiple queries in parallel.

db.js:

```
import mysql from 'promise-mysql';
import env from '../../../env.config.json';

const db = async (sql, descriptor, serializedParameters = []) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
                host: env.DB.HOST,
                user: env.DB.USER,
                password: env.DB.PASSWORD,
                database: env.DB.NAME,
                port: env.DB.PORT
            })
            if (connection && env.ENV === "development") {
                //console.log(/*"There is a connection to the db for: ", descriptor*/);
            }
                let result; 

                if(serializedParameters.length > 0) {
                    result = await connection.query(sql, serializedParameters)
                } else result = await connection.query(sql);
                connection.end();
                resolve(result);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR pool.db: " + e);
            reject(e);
        };         
    });
}

export default db;
```

This is an example of how I would create a connection to query the db

inventory.js:

```
import db from '../API/db';

export const selectAllFromBuildItems = () => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const getAllBuildItems = "SELECT * FROM mydb.build_items;"
            const response = await db(getAllBuildItems, "AllBuildItems");

            resolve(response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR inventory.selectAllFromBuildItems: " + e);
            reject(e);
        } 
    });   
};
```

How can I change my code so that I use a `pool` instead.  I have a lot of different queries that can be called from our application so I'm not quite sure what the right approach for this would be.  I saw some people say that I should create the `pool` once and then use it throughout the application, but I don't know where that would go.  If anyone has any suggestions on how I can make this switch, that would help me out a lot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the pool. Better if you create once when you run your application.
If it is in different file then you have export here and import in required file.

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host:     env.DB.HOST,
  user:     env.DB.USER,
  password: env.DB.PASSWORD,
  database: env.DB.NAME,
  connectionLimit: 10
});
```

I had to create this prototype function as the library had a bug of close connection was not returning the connection to the pool.

```
pool.prototype.releaseConnection = function releaseConnection(connection) {
    return this.pool.releaseConnection(connection.connection);
};
```

Funtion for getting connection from the pool that is created earlier.
If you want you can call pool.getConnection() in all your query functions.

```
function connect() {
  return pool.getConnection().then(function(connection) {
    return connection
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("Error Creating Connection");
    throw e;
  });
}
```

Now this is your query function to get data from dd.

```
function selectAllFromBuildItems() {
  var sql_query = `SELECT * FROM mydb.build_items`;
  return connect().then(function(conn) {
    return conn.query(sql_query).then(function(rows) {
      pool.releaseConnection(conn);
      return rows;
    });
  }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR inventory.selectAllFromBuildItems: " + e);
      throw e;
  });
}
```

Update: Descriptions are added. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is good information, but there is no description as to what part of my code this would be replacing, other than the obvious query functions.

Comment: @Michael, Though the segmented code would describe it. Updating.

Comment: A couple questions I have:  if the pool limit is only 10, if I call say 11 db queries at the same time will I have to wait for the 10 to finish first before I can call the 11th?  Also if there was an error in my query it doesn't look like it would release that connection back to the pool, or am I wrong?

Comment: I dont remember, its been a long time I studied their docs. It should return the connection to the pool before throwing the query error.

Comment: When the connectionLimit is set to 10, the db driver will make maximum 10 connections to the database.
If all 10 connections are active (haven't yet been released), then the 11th request for a connection (pool.getConnection()) will be in queue. The driver will wait until any of the active connections gets released back to the pool. So the 11th request will not get an error or no response but delayed.

Comment: You can even control more using the other options, like: set waitForConnections : false.
Or, if you want the driver to return an error if, say, there are 25 requests queued to receive a connection, set queueLimit : 25. Very next one will be rejected after queue size 25.
@Michael

Comment: If it works for you. Please choose as accepted answer.

Comment: This is all very good info, but it's hard for me to except this as the answer because I'm using promises with async / await and you are not.  Also isn't it possible to just call ```pool.query(sql, serializedParameters)```.  Doesn't that handle connection creation and connection release, without having to do it manually?

Comment: It returns promise.

Comment: I see that you are returning promises, but there is no async / await being used.

Comment: then and catch does the same thing bro.

Comment: `
connect().then(function(conn) {
   //use conn here
    });
  }).catch(function(e) {
      //handle error here
  });
`
`
var conn = await connect();
//use conn here
`

Both does same thing.

Comment: That's my bad, I will give this a try.